# Switch primary key constraint to a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key

I want to switch the primary key away from my existing identity column 
to a different column.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ParkingLot
(
  ID      int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Address ???,
  Status  ???, 
  newID   ???
);
```

I want to remove the primary key on the `ID` column and instead have `newID` be the primary key (this is a new column but it is already populated with values).

Comment: No, you probably shouldn't do that.  Just declare `address` to be unique.

Comment: [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) does not mean what you think it means. You can't make "address" an identity column, since an address is (usually) not a numeric column. Please clarify what exactly you want to change.

Comment: What I need eventually is to change the values of the ID column (That is a primary key). So I've read that I need to create new column ->define her as the the primary key ->delete the old primary key.  

So I need to know how to define the new column as primary key instead the "old" one

Comment: I've created new column with the values that I need and now I want to make her as the primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Drop primary Key constraint and Re-Add a new one**

You have to drop the primary key constraint and add a new one

*Drop primary key Constraint*

```
-- Return the name of primary key.  
SELECT name  
FROM sys.key_constraints  
WHERE type = 'PK' AND OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 
N'Tablename';  
GO  
-- Delete the primary key constraint.  
ALTER TABLE Production.Tablename
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Tablename;  
GO
```

*Add new primary key Constraint*

```
ALTER TABLE Tablename ADD CONSTRAINT pk_NewPrimary PRIMARY KEY (Newid)
```

**References**

- [Delete Primary Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-primary-keys#TsqlProcedure)
- [Change primary key column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844324/change-primary-key-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to remove the identity column... they just want a different column to serve as the primary key. At least the way I read it. So a new table should not be necessary (even if they want to remove the `ID` column, that can also be done without the need for a new table).

Comment: @AaronBertrand you're right. i remove the first method and updated my answer. thx for the remark